# Android Bluetooth and sending an unsigned Hex value

Tags: android, bluetooth, byte, arrays, unsigned-integer

I am currently working on a Android application that takes values from a text box and then sends it over bluetooth, all operations are in Hex values.

I have a convertion method that can take the string make give me the unsigned integer for the string, but once i place it in the byte array it becomes signed and the board that receives this cannot do signed hex.

This is how the process works:

```
//sample string to send
String toSend = "0BDD";

//sending the byte[] to the board over bluetooth
btOutputStream.write(SendByteData(toSend));

// --- perform the conversion to byte[] ---
public static byte[] SendByteData(String hexString)
{
    byte[] sendingThisByteArray = new byte[hexString.length()/2];
    int count  = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < hexString.length() - 1; i += 2 )
    {
        //grab the hex in pairs
        String output = hexString.substring(i, (i + 2));

        //convert the 2 characters in the 'output' string to the hex number
        int decimal = (int)(Integer.parseInt(output, 16)) ;

        //place into array for sending
        sendingThisByteArray[count] =  (byte)(decimal);

        Log.d(TAG, "in byte array = " + sendingThisByteArray[count]);
        count ++;
    }

    return sendingThisByteArray;
}
```

The issue is as follows:
When the for for loop runs through the string and picks up "0B" it correctly gives me integer 11; then when the loop runs through "DD" it give me integer 221 which is also correct

When I perform the operation of

```
sendingThisByteArray[count] =  (byte)(decimal);
```

11 gets correctly placed in sendingThisByteArray[0]
but for sendingThisByteArray[1] the number 221 gets changed to -35

I know that Java has signed bytes.. is there a way to put/place/change the byte array so i can place and number 221 or any other value higher than 127?

your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from a signed integer to unsigned byte like this, by binary AND'ing it with 0xFF:

```
sendingThisByteArray[count] =  (byte)(decimal & 0xFF);
```

This way you can send values from 0 to 255

Comment: It should definitely be working, so the fault is whatever is doing the re-interpreting, be it your debug code, the logic on the bluetooth device or both. One final thought, where exactly are you seeing "-35"? When using "& 0xFF", If that "-35" value is being displayed through bluetooth, then it is already interpreting the full 256 values and you can only get -128 to +127. Perhaps you could elaborate what you mean by "the board cannot do signed hex"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, when i tried to do unsigned hex into a byte array it would always put a sign, i had to create single byte to retain the unsigned hex

int zeroA = (int)(Integer.parseInt("0D", 16));
sendStream.write(unsignedToBytes((byte) zeroA));